# If $ f_n\to f $ strongly in $ L^2 $, show that $ f\to f $ strongly in $ H^{-1} $.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

If $ f_n\to f $ strongly in $ L^2(\Omega) $. Then we can regard $ f_n $ and $ f $ as linear functionals on $ H_0^1(\Omega) $ with $ \langle f_n,\varphi\rangle =\int_{\Omega}f_n \varphi dx $ and $ \langle f,\varphi\rangle =\int_{\Omega}f \varphi dx $. Then can I say that $ f_n\to f $ strongly in $ H^{-1}(\Omega) $?
My thought is as follows $$ \left\|f_n-f\right\|_{H^{-1}(\Omega)}=\sup_{\varphi\in H_0^1(\Omega),\varphi\neq 0}\frac{|\langle f_n-f,\varphi \rangle|}{\left\|\varphi\right\|_{H_0^1(\Omega)}}. $$
Meanwhile we have $$ |\langle f_n-f,\varphi \rangle|=\left|\int_{\Omega}(f_n-f) \varphi dx\right|\leq \left\|f_n-f\right\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\left\|\varphi\right\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq \left\|f_n-f\right\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\left\|\varphi\right\|_{H_0^1(\Omega)}. $$
This, together with the statements above, imply that $ \left\|f_n-f\right\|_{H^{-1}(\Omega)}\to 0 $.
I want to ask if my statement is true. I am not sure about it as someone said to me that it is not true by using the Sobolev embedding theorem.

Comment: This is true....